# Verifying that Spring controller parameter is not null

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, controller

If I have a controller that takes an Integer as a parameter that can be null as such

```
someFunc(...,...
     @RequestParam(required=false) Integer integerObjThatCanBeNull,...){
     return anotherFunc(...,integerObjThatCanBeNull...);
}
```

and then passes integerObjThatCanBeNull to anotherFunc as such

```
someFunc(..., int integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull...){...
```

How can I check in someFunc if integerObjThatCanBeNull was null or not when initially passed in?

Comment: you cannot do a simple if(integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull== null) ?

Comment: "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null"
is the error I received when I tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are Unboxing the Integer in your original request into `int` in the `someFunc`, and you can't do a null check on a primitive.

do this

```
someFunc(..., Integer integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull)
if(integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull== null)
```

**NOTE**

In the original code, when `null` comes in from the service and is passed to `someFunc`, it will throw `NullPointerException` because you are trying to Autobox a null value into `int`. In the solution provided if you do not return after performing the logic in the if statement you can get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Is that the only option? I don't want to break other code by changing the type to Integer

Comment: In the contrary, you fix a potential nullpointer by adding the check for null here. Autoboxing of null into int will break the call.

Comment: @rob but wouldn't this be the same issue they are facing since they are getting Integer in the service and then Autoboxing into the method ? I explained to do this way because it seem he couldn't perform the check outside the someFunc. But yes you ar right Autoboxing of null will cause issues. I will add note about that.

Comment: @EduardoDennis I am with you on this one, just tried to explain they he does not change behaviors, but fixes a bug by explicitly handling null values, which up till now would have caused nullpointer exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your parameter to Integer and do a simple null check. If your parameter is of type int, you will not get a null value here, but an exception earlier. In fact "int integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull" is quite a funny declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple null check before the return.
Otherwise, if you want your code cleaner you can use defaultValue, to force it to 0 for instance if the integer is null.
If it can not be null then you may change the 'require' to true.

You can even do both like this

```
@RequestParam(required=true, defaultValue=0)
```

Comment: that wouldnt work, in the method someFunc he wouldnt be able to determine if the user sent 0 or it was defaulted.

Comment: This is why I said that he can make a null check or set it to 0 as default. If in his case he is aware that 0 can never be chosen by the user then he will know that something went wrong... Just showed how @RequestParam's capabilities :)

Answer (score 0):

Primitive type variables cannot receive `null` values. If not assigned, these will assume it's *zero*, or *default* values (Ex: `0` for `int`, `0.0f` for `float`, `false` for boolean, etc.).

If your `int` parameter of `someFunc` need to be expressed as null on the method business logic, the interface is badly designed and you should change it. Keep your `Integer` at `someFunc` signature.

Answer (score -1):

you must check integerObjThatCanBeNull!=null when you call this function

```
someFunc(..., int integerPrimitiveThatCanBeNull...){...
```

Comment: this doesnt work because you cant check for null against a primitive

Comment: @EduardoDennis: Looks like he's saying check it before calling `anotherFunc`.  The first function takes an `Integer`, so there is an opportunity for a null check.